# Update data validation value when source data is changed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to update the selected value in a data validation list ('Roster!A2') when the source data is changed on the sheet 'Console' by user input from the sidebar. I am writing the data to 'Console' from the sidebar by using setValues.

My current solution (based on an old post) works as expected, but only when the cells are manually edited on the 'Console' sheet. I understand onEdit() does not work with cells changed by setValue.

I found a similar post addressing the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32016776/google-apps-script-make-onedit-recognize-setvalue-changes), but the post is over 7 years old. Is there a better way to do this now?

Current code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const { source, range, oldValue, value } = e;
  if (!oldValue || !value || range.getSheet().getName() !== "Console") {
    return;
  }
  const target = source.getRange("Roster!A2")
  changeOptions(target, oldValue, value)
}

function changeOptions(target, search, replaceWith) {
  target
    .createTextFinder(search)
    .matchCase(true)
    .matchEntireCell(true)
    .matchFormulaText(false)
    .replaceAllWith(replaceWith)
}
```

Comment: i might need a little more info. i'm assuming your data validation rule is a comma separated list. is there a reason your data validation rule is not just directly referencing the source range in "Console"?

Comment: Just call the change options function from the sidebar

Comment: The data validation is referencing the source range directly. For example, source data is 'A, B, C'. The user selects 'C' in the data validation dropdown. Then the user changes the value of 'C' via the sidebar form to be 'E.' The source data is updated correctly, but the data validation now shows invalid because it still shows 'C'. I need a way to update it to the current value, 'E'.

Comment: Source range is a column of 26 cells (Console!C42:C67).

Comment: okay, so the issue is really the display value in the cell where the data validation dropdown resides?

Comment: Correct, because all other changes to the data validation should update because they are linked to the source. I'm just not sure when multiple source data points are changed, how to retrieve the correct one that should be associated to replace the displayed value.

Comment: the value in the cell itself that contains the dropdown is not linked to anything. it's just a value in the cell and will stay the same unless acted upon. when the change is made to the value as you describe, you likely only need to set the value of that cell (where the data validation is)  to the new value as well.

Comment: In other words, when the person changes the value from the sidebar, whatever function is being used to set the values of the list in "Console" just needs to also set the value of the cell, where the value was selected in the dropown, to the new value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252907/discussion-between-meesterzee-and-jlmosher).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include something like this in the function that is updating the source range in "Console" when someone changes a value from the side bar form. This function should be called before the source range is set.

```
function updatetargetValue(newArray) {
  var targetCellValue = SpreadsheetApp
    .getActive()
    .getSheetByName('Roster')
    .getRange('A2')
    .getValue();

  var sourceTable = SpreadsheetApp
    .getActive()
    .getSheetByName('Console')
    .getRange('C42:C67')
    .getValues();

  var targetIndex = sourceTable.findIndex(a => a[0] == targetCellValue);
  //console.log(targetIndex);

  if (targetIndex > -1) {
    var newTargetValue = newArray[targetIndex][0];

    SpreadsheetApp
      .getActive()
      .getSheetByName('Roster')
      .getRange('A2')
      .setValue(newTargetValue);
  } else {
    console.log('did not find "' + targetCellValue + '" in source range')
  }
}
```